# Using hashing algorithm in CAPL (CANoe)

Tags: capl, canoe

I want to implement a hashing algorithm like md5 in CAPL (CANoe). Is there any built-in hashing function in CAPL?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to create a CAPL Dll which implements your hash-algorithm in C++ and include it via `#pragma library()` in your code.
There is an example in "CANoe Sample Configurations\Programming\CAPLdll". For more infos take a look at the chapter "CAPL DLL" in your CANoe help.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a built in hash function in CAPL, the closest I've been able to find is a checksum calculation function. (J1939CalcChecksum) Anyhow you can use the [CANoe .NET API](https://vector.com/portal/medien/cmc/application_notes/AN-IND-1-011_Using_CANoe_NET_API.pdf), once you are using .NET you can call its [hashing libraries.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm(v=vs.110).aspx)
The reference for CANoe .NET API is in Vector's page in the provided [link.](https://vector.com/portal/medien/cmc/application_notes/AN-IND-1-011_Using_CANoe_NET_API.pdf)